# Remove distance Display:Flex

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a navigation that pushes both div containers on the right side, under the navigation when you go into smartphone view. I try it with Display:flex
however I get this spacing left and right. How can I get rid of that

```css
.container-div {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(176, 243, 221);
}

.container-div div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-div">
  <div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center header-phone">
    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x"></i>
    <div class="col text-center ">
      <h5>Rufen Sie uns an</h5>
      <h5>+49 7433 2106989</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center  header-mail">
    <h5 class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center text-center">Kontakt</h5>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand.. you want the two divs will be under the nav?

Comment: #Yarin Levi Yes, as soon as I reduce the display size, the two divs should jump under the navbar. If I increase the display size both divs should move back into the navbar as you can see on the picture but without the space left and right.

Comment: Try *{margin:0,padding:0,box-sizing:border-box;}

Comment: #Yarin Levi Thank you very much. It is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Note that your HTML has an error, an extra/unmatched `</div>` tag at the end.

Comment: #David Thomas Which </div> do you mean?

Comment: I was happy to help. Don't forget to signal that the answer is helpful.

Comment: @MichaelBrilz Use @ instead # for tagging people.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi ok :)